# Why use Imag function with a real in argument?

Tags: matlab

I want to translate a matlab code in C++ and I have got some difficulties to understand matlab code. It is about [quaternion](https://sourceforge.net/p/qtfm/svncode/HEAD/tree/trunk/qtfm/) and code is [qfft2.m](https://sourceforge.net/p/qtfm/svncode/HEAD/tree/trunk/qtfm/@quaternion/qfft2.m)

X is a matlab quaternion and source code is :

```
C1 = fft2(complex(real(scalar(X)),      real(x(X))));
C2 = fft2(complex(imag(scalar(X)),      imag(x(X))));
C3 = fft2(complex(real(     y(X)), S .* real(z(X))));
C4 = fft2(complex(imag(     y(X)), S .* imag(z(X))));
```

I think complex function doc is [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html)
I suppose X (quaternion) is q+x i + y j + z k
and I understand that x(X) is x and y(X) is y and z(X) is z and scalar(X) is q

imag function doc is [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imag.html) 
My problem is : 
complex(imag(scalar(X)),      imag(x(X)))

If I understand well `imag(scalar(X))` and `imag(x(X))`  are  always 0 (imaginary part of real is 0) and then `complex(imag(scalar(X)),imag(x(X)))` is 0. I think I 'm wrong.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: This bit of code is inside a conditional statement that guarantees that `X` is complex.

Comment: X is a quaternion. But complex(imag(scalar(X)),imag(x(X))) is it always 0 ?

Comment: look at the code for `isreal`: it is only real if all components `x` `y` and `z` are real. So in the `else` branch, where this code runs, at least one of those is complex (has an imaginary component).

Comment: Ok I missed this. I realize now that my link to complex function is wrong because I must read source code in module @ quaternion. Thanks